# Dualboot with windows 11 and ubuntu boot issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, grub-efi

I am Using Lenovo laptop with i5 Processor.
I kept dual boot with windows 11 and ubuntu. sometimes while booting into ubuntu screen stuck with data like below.
[image]

```
installed Ubuntu details:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Like above i am facing issue sometimes when ever i booted into ubuntu.
Kindly please guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: Which kernel and Nvidia proprietary driver are you using?  Updates may leave you with an updated kernel whose Nvidia driver pieces are held back by phasing. Can you select an older kernel in grub (under advanced)?